# Can I get a smaller toilet installed? (picture included)

Tags: bathroom, water, floor, toilet, pipe

At the bottom is a picture of my toilet, where you can see the toilet pipe that enters the floor and that there is ~7 cm of space between the water container and the wall.

**Question**

Does there exist toilets where the pipe it bent/curved backwards, so the toilet is closer to the wall, and therefore gives more space in front of the toilet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never seen a toilet with a rough in like that.  Anywho, they make toilet flanges with an offset.  The offsets come in different sizes. 
[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot =) Does the type of toilets have a special name, where such an offset can me mounted?

Comment: This will not work in every situation, and can be quite a bit of work to install. You'll have to have access to the plumbing below the toilet to install an offset flange, or you'll have to raise the toilet up to compensate for the height of the fitting (at which time, you could simply re-plumb the drain and avoid using this fitting altogether).